# How do I see what is being tested in Chrome Canary, on an ongoing basis?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-canary

What advances are being tested in Canary?  How is feedback from users/testers received and responded to?

Comment: Regarding the proposed duplicate: it addresses what Canary is, but I don't see where it addresses what was asked in this question at all.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple really, You join the chromium group of open source developers... And you get to see everything!

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you would describe how to do that.

Comment: Google support forums are used for feedback. Chrome canary is the beta version where all new features are tried out before being released into the mainstream versions...